# "Functions may not be part of a struct or union" when trying to use a constructor for a struct

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I am wondering if this is a compiler specific problem or not. I've seen examples of the use of constructors for a struct in C++.

I have something like:

```
struct Example
{
   Example()
   {
   }
};
```

I still get this compiler error "Functions may not be part of a struct or union". I am using the very old Borland 4.5 compiler (best not to ask why...).

(And yes, this is done in C++).

Comment: Are you sure you are not compiling code as C?

Comment: Should be valid, maybe Borland 4.5 is set to pure C mode? Don't really know, just a suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling as C++?  The above is invalid C, but is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: It is set to C++, but I'll try a different version to see if I get the same issue.

Comment: What if you change the `struct` keyword into `class` (at least this should tell if it is C or not, or if the compiler has a specific problem with structs.)

Comment: Alright, when I change the struct to a class, I get a declaration syntax error. That should indicate that it is trying to compile it as C code. Now to find out why it's doing this... Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Just a guess: is your file extension c? Try changing it to cpp or cc. Maybe that auto-selects c++ mode.

Comment: After changing `struct` to `class`, did you make the constructor public?  If it's still private, you'd get an error when you tried to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help myself: Why?

Using a compiler that announces it's support for Windows 95 is sort of interesting. The C++ standard is from 1998, so anything published before that is perhaps not up to date? :-)

Other than that, the code is perfectly ok.